# get REST APi response in another route

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using Express with generator

I want to use JSON response of Rest Api in another route
like this :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/api/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    res.json($something); // generate json object       
});


router.get('/show', function(req, res, next){

   router.get(/api/12,function(request, response){
      res.send(request.body); 
   });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you extract the middleware function used for `/api/:id/` so you can reuse it (recommended) or you need to issue a proper request. `router.get` does not request the resource, as you seem to think, it rather sets up a route.
So, I'd go for:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var getResource = function(req, res, next) {
    //use req.params.id to look up resource
    res.json($something); // generate json object       
}
router.get('/api/:id', getResource );

router.get('/show', function(req, res, next){
  req.params.id = "12";
  return getResource(req, res, next);
});
```